# Recycler view v25.2.0 not showing item is the adapter count is 1

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was using recyclerview v 23.2.1 and then move everything to 25.2.0. It works well, but there is one problem. For example, i have apps that can display list of different items in different cities. When i choose the city that just have one item it is blank. I must move my finger to the screen to work well. But, in older version it's just fine. I also tried to give Handler before `notifyItemInserted` method to avoid scroll callback exception. That's not work too. So i tried with `notifyDataSetChanged` method. But the animation has gone if i do like that. So, i just give the recyclerView to smoothScroll to position 0. It works well. But, is there any alternative way? It looks weird if i check like that for the first page. This is the `refreshItems` method

```
public void refreshItems(List<T> items) {
    mItems.clear();
    mItems.addAll(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

and this is the `addItems` method

```
public void addItems(List<T> items) {
    mItems.addAll(items);
    int nDuplicate = 0;
    if (mOnCheckDuplicateListener != null)
      nDuplicate = mOnCheckDuplicateListener.onCheckDuplicate(mItems);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(getItemCount() - (items.size() - nDuplicate), getItemCount() - 1);
  }
```

If i added items using addItems method on the first page when the count data from api is just 1. Whenever i changed a city, it blanks, i must move my finger to the screen to works well. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: can you share with us some code

Comment: @Mr.Blue I have edited and give some snippet